# Can i put defs on random.choice in python?

Tags: windows-10, python-3.7

I'm working on a chatbot in python and I was wondering if I can use functions in random.choice because I want to have random chats and not always the same path.
This is the piece of code that I wrote to try if it works

```py
    def start():
        start = input("do u wanna chat? (y/n) ")

    if start == "n":
        no()

    if start == "y":
        test = random.choice([bot0(),bot1(),bot2])

    def bot0():
        print("do something 0")    #i added the numbers to know who is who
        start()

    def bot1():
        print("do something 1")
        start()

    def bot2():
        print("do something 2")
        start()
```

But when i try to run it, he returns me only "do something 0"...
What can i do to have random chats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way that you wrote it it won't work because those functions have not been defined yet. [Random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) can take a list of parameters but that list only has null elements currently so it won't work as intended. Below is a script that should be better

```
from numpy import random

def bot0():
    print("do something 0") 
    start()


def bot1():
    print("do something 1")
    start()


def bot2():
    print("do something 2")
    start()


def start():
    start = input("do u wanna chat? (y/n) ")

    if start == "n":
        return print("Thank you have a nice day") #no() function 

    elif start == "y":
        test = random.choice((1,3))

        if test == 1:
            bot0()

        elif test == 2:
            bot1()

        elif test == 3:
            bot2()

        else: 
            print("Somehow random choice messed up")

    else:
        print("Please type y/n to communicate with me. Goodbye")

start()
```

Comment: THANKS I LOVE U MAN! I WAS TRYING TO FIND A SOLUTION FOR WEEKS